# IndexingError: ('Too many indexers', 'occurred at index Label') - Function works with a training_set but not the real set

Tags: python, pandas, naivebayes

I'm experiencing an issue where one function essentially works for a training set but the code doesn't translate over to the entire dataset? Each time I've tried debugging it, I've always ran into issues with the columns. Either certain columns don't exist in the real dataset for me to run my computation OR I get:

```
IndexingError: ('Too many indexers', 'occurred at index Label')
```

I'm hoping someone can help me spot the problem as I've been wrestling with it for a couple of days now. I'll share the code samples below, starting with the training set which seems to be producing the results I'm looking for:

```
vocabulary = list(set([]))

for sentence in sms_dataset['SMS'].str.split():
    for word in sentence:
        vocabulary.append(word)
    
training_set = sms_dataset.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=1).reset_index()

for word in vocabulary:
    training_set[word] = 0
    training_set.loc[training_set['SMS'].str.contains(word), word] += 1
```

Output:

| SMS | good | night | sen | told | thank | you | baby | congratulations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yo you around just got my car back | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| good do you think you could send me some pix i... | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| hurt me tease me make me cry but in the end of... | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| i dnt wnt to tlk wid u... | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| wat time ü finish... | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

When I run the given function on the training set below, everything seems to work out:

```
def Naive_Bayes_spam_filter(sms_c, label_c, df):
    """
    Function is designed to predict whether a given column of SMS texts are spam messages or not. 
    The output should match the given label already provided and, in theory, should carry over to the test set.
    """   
    ## Calculating the constants of the dataset
    vocabulary = sms_c.split()
    
    p_ham_trg = label_c.value_counts(normalize=True)[0]
    p_spam_trg = label_c.value_counts(normalize=True)[1]
    n_vocab = len(vocabulary)
    alpha = 1

    n_ham_trg = label_c.value_counts()[0]
    n_spam_trg = label_c.value_counts()[1]      
    
    p_spam_given_sms = p_spam_trg #1
    p_ham_given_sms = p_ham_trg #1
    for word in vocabulary:
        ## Calculating the parameters
        p_word_given_spam = (df.loc[label_c == "spam", word].sum() + alpha) / (n_spam_trg + alpha *  n_vocab)
        p_spam_given_sms *= p_word_given_spam
        
        p_word_given_ham = (df.loc[label_c == "ham", word].sum() + alpha) / (n_ham_trg + alpha *  n_vocab)
        p_ham_given_sms *= p_word_given_ham
    
    if p_spam_given_sms > p_ham_given_sms:
        return "Spam!"
    elif p_spam_given_sms < p_ham_given_sms:
        return "Legit"
    elif p_spam_given_sms == p_ham_given_sms:
        return "Requires human attention"

training_set['p_spam_or_ham'] = training_set['SMS'].apply(Naive_Bayes_spam_filter, args=(training_set['Label'], training_set))
print(training_set[['Label', 'p_spam_or_ham']].tail(3))
```

Output:

| Label | p_spam_or_ham |
| --- | --- |
| spam | Spam! |
| ham | Legit |
| spam | Spam! |

But when I try adding the same logic to another function and applying it to the entire dataset, rather than the training set, I run into issues:

```
def Naive_Bayes_spam_filter(df, sms_c, label_c):
    """
    Function is designed to predict whether a given column of SMS texts are spam mesages or not.  
    The output should match the given label already provided and, in theory, should carry over to the test set.
    """
    vocabulary = list(set([]))

    for sentence in sms_c.str.split():
        for word in sentence:
            vocabulary.append(word)
        
    p_ham_trg = label_c.value_counts(normalize=True)[0]
    p_spam_trg = label_c.value_counts(normalize=True)[1]
    n_vocab = len(vocabulary)
    alpha = 1

    n_ham_trg = label_c.value_counts()[0]
    n_spam_trg = label_c.value_counts()[1]
    
    p_spam_given_sms = p_spam_trg 
    p_ham_given_sms = p_ham_trg 
    
    for word in vocabulary:
        df.loc[word] = 0
        df.loc[sms_c.str.contains(word), word] += 1
        
        p_word_given_spam = (df.loc[label_c == "spam", word].sum() + alpha) / (n_spam_trg + alpha *  n_vocab)
        p_spam_given_sms *= p_word_given_spam
        
        p_word_given_ham = (df.loc[label_c == "ham", word].sum() + alpha) / (n_ham_trg + alpha *  n_vocab)
        p_ham_given_sms *= p_word_given_ham
    
    if p_spam_given_sms > p_ham_given_sms:
        return "Spam!"
    elif p_spam_given_sms < p_ham_given_sms:
        return "Legit"
    elif p_spam_given_sms == p_ham_given_sms:
        return "Requires human attention"

sms_copy = sms.copy()
sms_copy['SMS'] = sms_copy['SMS'].str.lower()
sms_copy['SMS'] = sms_copy['SMS'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')

sms_copy['Bayes_Judgement'] = sms_copy.apply(Naive_Bayes_spam_filter, args=(sms_copy['SMS'], sms_copy['Label']))
sms_copy[['Label', 'Bayes_Judgement']].head(20)
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-dda713c3edda> in <module>
      3 sms_copy['SMS'] = sms_copy['SMS'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')
      4 
----> 5 sms_copy['Bayes_Judgement'] = sms_copy.apply(Naive_Bayes_spam_filter, args=(sms_copy['SMS'], sms_copy['Label']))
      6 sms_copy[['Label', 'Bayes_Judgement']].head(20)

~\Documents\Anaconda Package\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6485                          args=args,
   6486                          kwds=kwds)
-> 6487         return op.get_result()
   6488 
   6489     def applymap(self, func):

~\Documents\Anaconda Package\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    149             return self.apply_raw()
    150 
--> 151         return self.apply_standard()
    152 
    153     def apply_empty_result(self):

~\Documents\Anaconda Package\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    255 
    256         # compute the result using the series generator
--> 257         self.apply_series_generator()
    258 
    259         # wrap results

~\Documents\Anaconda Package\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    284             try:
    285                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 286                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    287                     keys.append(v.name)
    288             except Exception as e:

~\Documents\Anaconda Package\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in f(x)
     76 
     77             def f(x):
---> 78                 return func(x, *args, **kwds)
     79         else:
     80             f = func

<ipython-input-22-f46657f5e989> in Naive_Bayes_spam_filter(df, sms_c, label_c)
     26     for word in vocabulary:
     27         df.loc[word] = 0
---> 28         df.loc[sms_c.str.contains(word), word] += 1
     29 
     30         p_word_given_spam = (df.loc[label_c == "spam", word].sum() + alpha) / (n_spam_trg + alpha *  n_vocab)

~\Documents\Anaconda Package\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1492             except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):
   1493                 pass
-> 1494             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1495         else:
   1496             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

~\Documents\Anaconda Package\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
    871 
    872         # no multi-index, so validate all of the indexers
--> 873         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
    874 
    875         # ugly hack for GH #836

~\Documents\Anaconda Package\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
    219         for i, k in enumerate(key):
    220             if i >= self.obj.ndim:
--> 221                 raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
    222             try:
    223                 self._validate_key(k, i)

IndexingError: ('Too many indexers', 'occurred at index Label')
```

Can anyone help me spot the issue?

Comment: Is what you give as _Output_ the whole and only output?

Comment: How does `sms_dataset['Label']` come about?

Comment: Hi @Armali, thanks for getting back to me. There's more to the output, I'll edit it and it to the question. As for your second question, `sms_dataset['SMS']` came from another copy of the `sms` dataset that I used. The content in that column is the same thing as `sms_copy['SMS']`. Let me know if there's anything I can clarify? This is my first time contributing to Stack Overflow and I'm just teaching myself at the moment so apologies for any mistakes in the formatting!

Comment: I'm still wondering how the `'Label'` column used in `training_set['p_spam_or_ham'] = training_set['SMS'].apply(Naive_Bayes_spam_filter, args=(training_set['Label'], training_set))` comes about.

Comment: `training_set['Label']` is pre-trained label that came with the dataset. It's there because to help gauge how accurate the model is at predicting the occurrence of spam messages (FYI - the `ham` label represents non-spam messages if that wasn't clear earlier).  (See part 2 of my comment below).

Comment: In another code box, I would compare the predictions that my model made with the pre-trained labels to measure its accuracy:

`legit_error = training_set.loc[training_set['Label'].eq('ham') & training_set['p_spam_or_ham'].eq('Spam!'), ['Label', 'p_spam_or_ham']]
false_positive_rate = len(legit_error) / len(training_set.loc[training_set['Label'] == 'ham'])
print("Legit messages classified as spam: {}".format(len(legit_error)), '\n', "False Positive Rate: {} % \n".format(round(false_positive_rate, 4) * 100))` 

( See part 3 of the comment)

Comment: Output:
`Legit messages classified as spam: 1161 
False Positive Rate: 30.220000000000002 %`

The model can still use fine tuning but I'm hoping you get the logic behind my model. Did this help to clear up your question?

Comment: Without the `'Label'` column, the shown code is not runnable and the error not reproducible, so I'd recommend give an example without `'Label'` data or just give sample `'Label'` data.